# Magento 2 - layered navigation, get available filterItems

Tags: magento-2.1, layered-navigation

I have a store with 2 product attributes: BRAND and COMPATIBILITY. All products have one BRAND and one COMPATIBILITY. At the moment both attributes are used to filter product in the Store.

I need to display COMPATIBILITY as a list of dropdown options when I click on BRAND.

[image]

The question is: how can I get the available COMPATIBILITY options for each BRAND?